# How can I compute the best outcome and keep it efficient?

Tags: c#, vb.net, artificial-intelligence

I building a game, and I need help about how to proceed here. This function might en up called often, up to each minute in the latest stage. I cant let it become a bottle neck and slow down, and the only way I can see it to brute force it, and I'm pretty sure it can be done in a better way.

I have (up to) 16 items.

I must place them in a 4x4 grid

Each item have 16 score (0 to 3k), depending on their position in the grid.

EDIT theres no algorith, just simple property  :

```
item A : position (0,0) = 2 point
item A :  position (0,1) = 123 point 
item A :  position (0,2) = 9 point
... 

item B :  position (0,0) = 0 point
item B :  position (0,1) = 0 point 
item B :  position (0,2) = 1224 point
....

If you set item A in position (0,0) and end your turn, your total socre is 2.
IF you set item A in posistion(0,0) + item B in position (0,2) than end your turn,  your total score is 1226
```

etc for each 16 items.

I could get in an array of each possible position for each item, and check for the total score of each result ... but building a array with 16! int each minute doesnt seems a very efficient way for me to do it.

How can I compute the best possible outcome (total score) ?

EDIT : seems scoring seems important ( i fail to see how though ) :

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Objects As List(Of BaseObject)

    Public Function Score(position) As Integer
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        For Each o In baseObject
            total += o.value(position)
        Next

        Return total
    End Function
End Class

Public Class RedObject
    inherits BaseObject

    property value as list(of integer)
end Class
```

Comment: Give a more concrete example. I.e. numbers you are putting and the best outcome you are trying to achieve. You can try to 3x3, just to show the concept - this can be brute forced.

Comment: I'm starting with 4x4 grid. it WILL increase in size eventually. when I get to 8! or 9! it does feel a bad idea to brute force it.

Comment: Forget grid size: you haven't explained the scoring algorithm; please do so, since that's pretty much the only way we can help.

Comment: Do you know if a local maximum is a global maximum? i.e. is your optimization function convex?

Comment: @lev I dont even know what you are meaning by convex function

Comment: Without algorithm of score point calculation it's hard to say if there's a better solution then brute force or not.

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı : sorry I though scoring was obvious, I add in detail.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier i didn't mean the final score calculation. item A position (0,0) equals 2 point but how?

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı Because I decide so ? this is just a random integer, theres no calculation on this .. Each item class will hold different object. some object increase the Item score for some position.

Comment: So each pair (x,y) has a fixed score per item? Or is that score changing throughout the game?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain see the edit for the score ... but I fail to see how it impact the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider writing a recursive routine that computes the values for each possibility. If you have performance issues you can limit the depth of the recursion with a parameter. In pseudo code this looks like:

```
GameBoard GetBestNextMove(GameBoard, recursiveDepth) {
    if (recursiveDepth == 0 || GameBoard.NoMovesRemaining()) return GameBoard;

    BestGameBoard = null;
    foreach (possibleMove) {
       GameBoard = GameBoard.Clone();
       GameBoard.MakeMove(possibleMove);
       GameBoard = GetBestNextMove(GameBoard, recursiveDepth - 1);
       if (GameBoard != null) {
         if (BestGameBoard == null) BestGameBoard = GameBoard;
         else if (GameBoard.Score > BestGameBoard) BestGameBoard = GameBoard;
       }
    }

    return BestGameBoard;
}
```

Again, this is PSEUDO code, but hopefully it gets you started down the right track.

Comment: @dew_w unless I fail to read it, this is just a (much) cleaner way to test each possible outcome ?

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier You might say so. Since I didn't know enough about the game I wrote a brute force approach that limits the depth of the search. The point of the limit is to make sure this doesn't continue forever for a complicated game (think "chess")

Comment: ok thanks. this is much more advanced than what I would've done. I didnt put in much info because its the mathematical way to get the outcome I wanted ( i'm sure it exist, I'm trying to google since 2 days on this, and found its relate to factorial function and binomial coefficient, but dont know math enough to understand it all)

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier If you want the mathematical specifics your probably going to have to explain the game better, I think!

Comment: the piece have a score for position, its just something I invented to automaticly decide if item A is in a better in (0,0) than  Item B. 

I dont understand why everyone focus on the score, its not even a real value.Its just a scoring system I invented to help me decide which position is best for different items.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier What you have already figured out from your comments is that games are basically math. So how you assign those math equations and the points you place on certain outcomes in a game are *critical* to the way you write the algorithm. You might find many different optimizations based on scoring one way versus another. You may even find outcomes that you can automatically ignore based on score. Hopefully this makes sense why scoring + the math is so important to the algorithm. Unless you are asking for something else, this is critical information!

Comment: There is no score ! I want the MATH to find how to get the best location, not full algorithm. 

item A is 3 point on row 1. item B is 2 point. if I can place only 1 item I want to automaticly choose item A. 

now I want that, but on a 2d and 3d scale. it seems alot simpler to assign a value, and ask for the best total score instead of a full algorithm.

Comment: Anyway, I'll start with this, and i,ll check as the game increase in size if it really gets too much. thanks for the snippet